# button attribute hiding checkbox in android 10

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to add button attribute to my checkbox in android.
But the checkbox gets hidden in android 10 devices.
On removing the button attribute, the checkbox is displayed.
What may be the root cause of the issue?

```
<CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@color/check_box_selector"
                android:checked="false"
                />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#00000000" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#00000000" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unchecked" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the wrong attribute for the default state, it should be `state_checked="false"`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unchecked" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Also why the color, not needes if you hace the drawable

Answer (score 0):

Why are you wanting to add button to checkbox? `Checkbox` already responds to user touches.